# "Cannot convert" issue with Member Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, member

I'm trying to make a simple program that will use for_each and a member function pointer in order to add to each element in a vector depending on the element's position (the comments in the code should explain it well enough).

However, I'm running into a single error and I can't figure out how to correct the mistake that I'm making (the error is also detailed in the comments below).

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class myClass
{
public:
  myClass()      : i_(0) {}
  myClass(int i) : i_(i) {}

  const int& Get() const   {return i_;}
  void Add(const int &arg) {i_ += arg;}

private:
  int i_;
};

template <typename RetType, typename ClassType, typename ArgType>
class MemFuncPointer
{
public:
  MemFuncPointer(RetType (ClassType::*_pointer) ()) : pointer(_pointer) {}
  RetType operator() (ClassType &element) {return(element.*pointer) ();}

private:
  RetType (ClassType::*pointer) (ArgType);
};

template <typename RetType, typename ClassType, typename ArgType>
MemFuncPointer<RetType, ClassType, ArgType> func(RetType (ClassType::*pointer) (ArgType) )
{
  return MemFuncPointer<RetType, ClassType, ArgType>(pointer);
  // The above line gets...
  // error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from
  // 'void (__thiscall myClass::* ) (const int &)' to
  // 'Functor<RetType,ClassType,ArgType>'
}

int main(void)
{
  // Create Vector v
  std::vector<myClass> v;

  // Push back ten 10's
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    v.push_back( myClass(10) );

  // Set two iterators
  std::vector<myClass>::const_iterator it = v.begin(), it_end = v.end();

  // Print the vector and newline
  for(; it != it_end; ++it)
    std::cout << it->Get() << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";

  // for_each
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), func(&myClass::Add));

  // Print the vector and newline
  for(it=v.begin(); it!=it_end; ++it)
    std::cout << it->Get() << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";

  // Final vector should be 
  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
}
```

Comment: `std::for_each` requires a unary functor, taking a `myClass` in this case. A member function takes a first, implicit parameter for `this`, so it is not a unary function. You would need to bind a `myClass` instance to it, or use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn). But note that `myClass::Add` expects an `int`, and you would be passing it a `myClass`. You would need an `Add` method taking `myClass`.

Comment: Custom-wrapping function pointers is not necessary if you can use`std::function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function pointer you passed in is different because of its parameter type.

In the following line, the `Add` function takes one parameter.

```
void Add(const int &arg) {i_ += arg;}
```

But `MemFuncPointer` takes no parameters:

```
MemFuncPointer(RetType (ClassType::*_pointer) ()) : pointer(_pointer) {}
```

That's why you got compile error.

---

To implement your logic, you cannot use `for_each`, because `for_each` doesn't pass the element position to the functor.

You can correct it this way:

1. Fix the type error.

   ```
   MemFuncPointer(RetType (ClassType::*_pointer) ()) : pointer(_pointer) {}
   RetType operator() (ClassType &element) {return(element.*pointer) ();}
   ```

   ---->

   ```
   MemFuncPointer(RetType (ClassType::*_pointer) (ArgType)) : pointer(_pointer) {}
   RetType operator() (ClassType &element, int i) {return(element.*pointer) (i);}
   ```
2. Write your version of `for_each`:

   ```
   std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), func(&myClass::Add));
   ```

   ---->

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   {
         func(&myClass::Add)(v[i], i);
   }
   ```

But I still don't think you need so complex code to do this work.